# How to connect to sql server using java jdbc and run sql agent job?

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-agent-job

I have 2-3 servers and each server have 20-25 SQL agent jobs.
So, I don't want to run these jobs manually. I just want to pass the server name and job name, so that it will run the job.

Comment: Are you able to schedule them, say every hour or 15 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I was able to automate the job run:
First of all, you have to create a java project and include sqljdbc4.jar file to your project's lib.
 
You can download the jar file from this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsqljdbc420jar.htm).

```
public class SQLMethod {

static void runJob(String serverName, String jobName) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    String sqlSerDriver = "jdbc:sqlserver://%s;integratedSecurity=true;";
    String Url = String.format(sqlSerDriver, serverName);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Url);
    String jobExString = "EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'%s'";
    String jobExcute = String.format(jobExString, jobName);
    CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(jobExcute);
    cs.execute();
    System.out.println("Job started..");
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    String serverName = " "; /*pass your server name here*/
    String jobName = " "; /*pass your job name here*/
    runJob(serverName, jobName);

}
}
```

Thanks :)